# ExtJS 3.4 - Have xtype: 'displayfield' show updated value?

Tags: javascript, extjs3

So I am working on legacy code. I have a grid that has an action button, when clicking this action button, it must enable the user to rename a certain value, change another field etc...

The problem I am facing is that when I click the edit button, I can see  in the console, that it is selecting the correct data and sending it to  the  form panel, but the form panel keeps displaying the firs selections data.
How to  fix this???

Some code:

```
// the filed that needs to display the newly selected rows data
items:[
    {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Route',
        id: 'route',
        name: 'route'
    }

...

Ext.getCmp('route').setValue( /** currently selected rows route **/ );
```

[image]

No matter what, it keeps on displaying values it first bound to, however in the console I can see the values change. I have even tried resetting the form after the submit and cancel methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a combination of your answers.
On the click of the action button, I created a new form, as [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5282479/joe-horn) suggested and then set the values of the different input fields.
To ensure that no data was kept and that each event loads the corresponding rows data I did as [Mohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4781787/mohit-saxena) suggested, and destroyed the form after submit/cancel. So each button creates and destroys a form.

Comment: could you please share  code snippet which worked for you.I am facing the same problem as you

Comment: I am unable to create a  fiddle or plunker at this stage. Leave me your e-mail and I will send you the snippet. But the principle is to create your form as Joe did. Then in the button event call a function that renders the form, does the post of the data, and in the end destroys the form as Mohit  suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with javascript variable instead of DOM/component selector.

```
var routeField = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Route',
    name: 'route'
});

....

items:[routeField]

....

routeField.setValue('A1');
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain how this will ensure that the selected value is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Destroy your formPanel when click on cancel button then check.